# Bernoulli - Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $Y_{n}$, $n≥0$ be an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli $(p)$ random variables for some fixed $p ∈
(0, 1).$

Let $X_{n} = Y_{n−1} + Y_{n}$ for $n ≥ 1$. Is $X_{n}$, $n≥1$ a Markov chain? If no explain why not. If
yes then determine the state space, the initial distribution, and the transition matrix.

We've just started studying Markov chains. By the Informal definition, it states that whatever happens in the future depends on the present state and not on the past.

For Bernoulli, the outcome of the $n^{th}$ toss is independent of the results of 1,2,......n-1.
If we know what happened at n-1, then any other information from the past is not required.

$$P(Y_{n+1} = j+1 / Y_{n} = j) = p $$ and

$$P(Y_{n+1} = j / Y_{n} = j) = 1-p $$

How can I related this information for $X_{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $Y_1 = 0, Y_2 = 1$; then $X_2 = 1$. What are the possibilities for $X_3$?

Now, suppose $Y_1 = 1, Y_2 = 0$. Again, $X_2 = 1$. What are the possibilities for $X_3$?

Comment: for the first case, it $X_{3}$ can be 1 or 2. And, for the second one, it can be 0 and 1.

Comment: Why aren't we taking a case when both $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ can be 0 or 1?

Comment: You're certainly permitted to consider those cases, but they're not as interesting because there is only one way to have them happen. This is as opposed to having $X_2=1$, which has two meaningfully distinct ways of occurring.

Comment: Now, if all I tell you is that $X_2=1$, the next question is: what will $X_3$ be?

Comment: It can be 0,1 or 2? Because X3 depends on Y2 which takes 0 and 1 and Y3 also can be 0 and 1.

Comment: What you said is true. Consider these scenarios, then: (1) I tell you that $X_2 = \mathbf{2}, X_3 = 1$. (2) I tell you that $X_2 = \mathbf{0}, X_3 = 1$. What do each of these imply about the probability that $X_4 = 2$?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks for forcing me to think. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Okay. Here's what I got :
1) If I have $X_{2} =2$ and $X_{3} =1$ : if $X_{2} =2$ that means $Y_{1} =1$ and $Y_{2} =1$. And $X_{3} =1$ which means $Y_{3} =0$ because $Y_{2} =1$. So, now if we try to solve for $X_{4} =2$ which is sum of Y3 and Y4. Y3 is already 0 and Y4 cannot be two - so it's not possible.

For second case : when X2 =0 which means both Y1 and Y2 are zero. X3 =1 means Y3 has to be 1 as Y2 is zero. Now, for calculating X4 =2 , Y4 has to be 1 because Y3 is also 1. In short X4 depends on what we have in X2 but to be a markov chain it should not depend on X2 right?

Comment: You've got it! ${}{}$

Comment: I think I am getting it. What if I had $X_{n} = Y_{n−1} + 2*Y_{n}$ instead? Will it be a Markov chain? I am trying the same approach, and I think it will be, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, it would. The "problem" with the original example was that the values of $Y_{n-1}, Y_n$ were mixed together to create $X_n$ in a way that couldn't be easily disentangled. By placing a $2$ where you did, you've solved that problem, and you could create coherent transition probabilities for the resulting Markov chain.

Comment: I understand everything now, but how could I write/explain it without giving specific examples?

Comment: That question is probably best asked of your instructor. But generally: to show that something is *not* a Markov chain, a specific example should be good enough, because you just need a single counterexample to the claim "at every state $x$, our next step $x$ should not depend upon *how* we arrived at $x$." To show that something *is* a Markov chain, specify the states it can be in, along with the transition matrix (i.e. a matrix of probabilities of traveling from each state to each other state in one step).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{\mathcal F_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ be the natural filtration of $X_n$. $\{X_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is not a Markov chain because
$$
\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n] = \mathbb E[Y_n+Y_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] = Y_n + \mathbb E[Y_{n+1}] = Y_n+p
$$
whereas
$$
\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid\sigma(X_n)] = \mathbb E[Y_n+Y_{n+1}\mid\sigma(X_n)] = \mathbb E[Y_n\mid\sigma(X_n)] + p,
$$
and $Y_n= X_n-Y_{n-1}$ is not $\sigma(X_n)$-measurable.

Comment: I just started Markov chains. I have no idea what you just did here.

Comment: A stochastic process $\{X_t:t\geqslant 0\}$ has the Markov property if and only if for each $0\leqslant s\leqslant t$ and each bounded measurable map $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the following identity holds:
$$
\mathbb E[f(X(t))\mid \mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[f(X(t))\mid \sigma(X_s)],
$$
where $$\sigma(X_s) = \{X_s^{-1}(B) : B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\},$$
with $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$. This does not hold for the process in your question.